# Querying dynamically a Firestore collection with AngularFire 2

Tags: angular, angularfire2, rxjs5

I'm trying to query a user collection with dynamically passed uids, following https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md steps.
For some reason, even if there're two existing ids in this collection, it only returns one.
Note that I'm still using the compat rxjs5 syntax for switchMap.

```
const ids$ = new Subject<string>();
const queryIds = ids$.switchMap(id => {
  this.afs.collection('user_previews', ref => {
    return ref.where('id', '==', id)).valueChanges()
  });
});

queryIds.subscribe(queriedIds => {
  console.log(queriedIds); // Logs only 1 value when there're 2 existing ids
});

this.friendRequests.forEach(request => {
  console.log(request.id_sent); // Logs 2 ids
  ids$.next(request.id_sent);
});
```

EDIT
It always returns the oldest user in the collection. It doens't matter how many ids are matched.

Comment: What does `console.log(id)` say in your callback? And what are the two ids in your DB?

Comment: It logs the two id strings. They both exist in user_previews collection in the DB but only one doc is returned in the subscription. It should return the matched two.